# How to convert an entry from a DB that can be null into a String?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable

I have a a populated `JTable` with various data. Now I'm trying to convert it into a `String` but in my DB they can be a `null` value so when I call this line:

```
String s = model.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
```

I get an exception, it's because it tries to convert a null value into string right?

How do I make it work?

Comment: `Object val = model.getValueAt(i,j);
  String s = val == null ? "" : val.toString();`

Comment: 1) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 3) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object cellObj = model.getValueAt(i,j);
String s;
if (cellObj == null) {
    s = null;
} else {
    s = cellObj.toString();
}
```

Comment: @Tom, was typo :).. fixed

Comment: JTable (valid for Java too) hasn't any issue with null, then set the String doesn't make me any sence (even can generete desribed NPE), not convert to the String, Object can do that ...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because when you retrieve the information from your data storage, you do not check whether or not it is `null`. So when you call `model.getValueAt(i,j)`, this is most likely returning a `null` value at some point. You do not check this, so you are calling `toString()` on a `null` value (`null.toString()`), which will cause your code to crash with a `NullPointerException`. I would suggest you use a `turnary` operator. This will check whether or not the value returned is `null` first, and then create the `String s` depending on whether or not it was `null`.

```
String s = ((model.getValueAt(i,j) == null) ? null : model.getValueAt(i,j).toString());
```

This will set your `String` to `null` if the record is `null`, otherwise set it to the record's value. OR, if you would like it to be an empty `String` (`""`) when the record does not exist, you can use:

`String s = ((model.getValueAt(i,j) == null) ? "" : model.getValueAt(i,j).toString());`

Comment: he has exception when null... so it must transform `null` into `""`  `== null) ? "" : model`....

Comment: My assumption is that the NPE was because the record (`model.getValueAt(i,j)`) was `null`, and if you call `.getString()` on a `null` object, it will cause a NPE. The poster did not state whether or not they wanted the value of `String s` to be `null` or `empty` when the record returned from `model.getValueAt(i,j)` is `null`. I've updated my answer to include both the empty and `null` variations, although my first answer correctly supports the original question. @JordiCastilla

Comment: @JordiCastilla, he probably gets an exception because `null.toString()` produces a null pointer exception. This would happen if the cell he retrieves from the table returns `null`. No where did the author of the question say he wants to convert a null into an empty string.

Comment: I've updated my answer again to explain why the NPE is happening. @GigaStore you are correct. Whoever downvoted, did it far too hastily without correctly reading the question that was asked.